# NEW : Installation did not complete successfully. See the IDE log for details - Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just installed Android studio, and when trying to create a new virtual device when downloading the recommended images for the system but each time i try i get this error: Installation did not complete successfully, See the IDE log for details. I have tried several solutions from online including checking the SDK path it's path is set well. I am using Android studio  version 3.1.0

Comment: Sorry, i had to start with the word new because the title already exists but the answers didn't work for me

Comment: Did you check if you have any connection/network/firewall issues? Sometimes ther SDKs does not downlo becuase of the repositories being block and that causes installation issues.

Comment: It would help if you would show the actual exception details from the log.

Comment: `See the IDE log for details`. Have you checked the logs by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

The problem: Installation did not complete successfully see the IDE log for details

I have already solved this problem.

1. If you have windows 10 and Android Studio 3.6.1 (or whatever), you should find this path `"\Android\android-sdk"` - usually you find it in `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk` - and find the emulator folder and delete it.
2. After that, go in the these folders `"\tools\bin"` and copy the whole path.
3. Open the command line program and write `CD` and paste that path and press Enter.
4. Usually, you will see like this: `"C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin>"`.
5. After that, write `"sdkmanager emulator"` like:
   `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin> sdkmanager emulator`

*You will see the **downloading** and **installing** of the **emulator**. And, your problem will be solved.*